# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at n.parseJSON (VM1366 jquery.min.js:4)
>       at ub (VM1366 jquery.min.js:4)
>       at x (VM1366 jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (VM1366 jquery.min.js:4)

The above is the error I get. I have searched and read the answers online and none is working for me.

I have two pages(they both use the same controller function) that I use to calculate prices with, one page is working fine and the other is giving me this error. I am passing data via ajax to my controller for querying from the database, and I return the queried data as a json.

My ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  },
  url: "<?php echo ci_site_url(); ?>project/calculate",
  type: "post",
  data: {
    "urgency": 3,
    "academiclevel": highschool,
    "words": 275
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    var h = data[0][0].highschool;
    var m = data[0][0].master;
    var u = data[0][0].undergraduate;
    var d = data[0][0].doctoral;
    var w = data[1].words;
    var c = parseFloat(data[2].currency);
    if (h) {
      document.getElementById('amount').value = h * w * c;
    }
    if (m) {
      document.getElementById('amount').value = m * w * c;
    }
    if (u) {
      document.getElementById('amount').value = u * w * c;
    }
    if (d) {
      document.getElementById('amount').value = d * w * c;
    }
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

My controller code:

```
public function calculate(){
     $urgency = $this->input->post('urgency');
     $academiclevel = $this->input->post('academiclevel');
     $words['words'] = $this->input->post('words');
     $currency['currency'] = $this->input->post('currency');

     $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT `$academiclevel` FROM `custom_prices` WHERE `deadline` = '$urgency'");
     $data = $sql->result();

     $f = [$data,$words, $currency];
     echo json_encode($f); 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [**your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). CodeIgniter has a ActiveRecord class to prevent this.

Comment: Please check if your code actually returns valid JSON. There might be a HTML formatted error message in there.

Comment: I can see the data that am posting but I am not getting a valid json as my response

Comment: Now, what did you get as your response?

Comment: Nothing at all... Its null

The status code is 302
The type is text/html
and the initiator is my jquery.min.js file

Comment: Does your code go inside success or error methods ? Also, paste ci_site_url() output by doing console.log()

Comment: @DpEN the code previously was not going inside the success but rather in the error method. Right now I solved it after realizing a had a logical error in my code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.post("<?php echo ci_site_url(); ?>project/calculate",
{
    urgency: 3,
    academiclevel: highschool
    words: "275"
},
function(results, status){
    var data = JSON.parse(results);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: $highschool is defined and $academiclevel has a value and the query result has a value. I am wondering why am not getting the json response in my success return

Comment: If you replace your code by the code above, what you get? Maybe the header of your request pose a problem

Comment: While above code may answer the question but a bit of explanation would be wise thing to do. Like pointing out why you have removed quotes, headers, etc. You will likely get negative attention with just posting the code.

Comment: @DpEN i'm not sure if the header pose the problem or not, for that i suggest him to try this code, if this code work so we can say that the problem is in the request header!

Comment: @louk -- A **recommendation** without **knowing** you can fix the problem is a **comment**  --  If you are *not sure* you're answer will fix the issue .. You shouldn't be answering the question, rather leaving a comment *suggesting* a fix in the OP ..

Comment: After many trials that proved futile, I realized it was a logical error brought about by a redirect in my construct. Thanks for the help guys I really appreciate. @louk The above code works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Zak Understand, when i t tried to leave comment the systeme told me that i don't have suffisant reputations (i started answering since 2 days), the reason why i set my response below as answer!